# If two Fredholm maps are in the same connected component then they are path connected

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $F,G$ be two Fredholm maps from a Hilbert space $H$ to itself, and let $Fred(H)$ denote the space of all such operators. I know that the space of bounded invertible operators on $H$ is path connected.

I have to prove using it that if $F$ and $G$ lie in the same connected component of $Fred(H)$ then there is a continuous path connecting the operators. I already could prove that $F$ and $G$ have the same index if and only there is a path connecting them, so perhaps it is more convenient to prove that if they are in the same connected component then they have the same index.

However I am more or less stucked. Any hints are appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$Fred(H)$ is an open subset of the set of bounded operators on $H$, which itself is path-connected. It is even a vector space.

You can then apply a general result that asserts that an open set $U$ in a  path-connected space has path-connected components. This is proven by considering the set of points that can be connected by a path to a given point. Such set will be open, so does its complement in $U$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But why is the set of bounded operators on $H$ path connected? Could you maybe show this just using that the set of invertible bounded operators on $H$ is path connected?

Comment: If $A$ and $B$ are two bounded operators, you can just take the segment $tA+(1-t)B$ to connect them.

Comment: Very quick and elegant proof. Thank you!